# Batch file read in var and write back

Tags: batch-file

I need to count every time a computer is turn off or restarted. Thus I believe i can do this with a batch file by adding it to the start menu. Thus everytime you turn on PC it will run.
When it runs it should

```
open c:\count.txt
read in the value on that text file
add 1 to it
write the value to the text file
exit.
```

but I have not used batch files much and could not figure out how to read in the number from the text file.

Comment: Alternatively, you may store such data in registry with `REG` or `SETX`.

Comment: i need to have least impact on the pc, messing with reg is risky or so i think.

Comment: Ok. By myself, I would prefer it to write to drive root path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on your idea (updating a counter in a file):

```
rem open c:\count.txt
rem read in the value on that text file
set /p count=<c:\count.txt
rem add 1 to it
set /a count+=1
rem write the value to the text file
>c:\count.txt echo.%count%
rem exit.
exit
```

Notice: Take care, that you choose a path the user has write access to. (`C:\` may not work without privileges)

Comment: Good example of "set /p" and "set /a".

Comment: i like this , its quick and easy for me to understand :D  One question i have though is how will this work if 1. the count.txt file got deleted? would it create the file again. would it give an error cause its a blank file? would it still add 1.. I could test these out i guess. just restarting a computer , or restarting this computer is something i dont want to do due to the applications running on it. but will if you can not answer these. Thanks Glen

Comment: if count.txt does not exist, `set /p` will give an error. Nevertheless, `set /a` will correctly "add" one. @foxidrive: thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution from MS-DOS days.  The c:\count.txt filesize isn't going to be an issue for any realistic number.

To reset the counter delete c:\count.txt

```
@echo off
>>c:\count.txt echo 1
echo Count is up to:
find /c "1" <c:\count.txt
```

Comment: I dont understand this, this will readin the count.txt and echo out first line right?  not sure what >>c:\count line does or the find.

Comment: Try it a few times - and examine the file.  That should make it clearer.

Comment: LOL not elegant, but functional! @GlenMorse: every run of the batch will add a line `1` to the file. The `find` counts the `1`s (`/c`)