# How to use CALL function in DOS 6.22?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have written a batch file that runs fine under Windows Command Prompt, but I would like to be able to run it after POST in DOS. I have copied my code to AUTOEXEC.BAT file which gets executed automatically; however it comes up with syntax errors once it reaches the call command and the rest.

```
echo. This script is counting the # of POSTs.
echo. The POST # value is saved in TEST.txt.
echo.

call:myPOSTTest

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (A:\TEST.txt)  do echo POST# %%x

echo. &pause&goto:eof
::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------

:myPOSTTest    - here starts my function identified by its label 

set var=0

if EXIST A:\TEST.txt (
     for /f %%x in (A:\TEST.txt) do (set /a var=%%x+1)
)

echo %var% >> A:\TEST.txt

goto END

:END
```

Thank You

Comment: I think it wasn't implemented there. But not 100% sure...

Comment: Out of curiosity what version of Windows are you running? You mentioned running this in the Windows Command Prompt, but you want to run it in DOS...

Comment: I don't think DOS 6.22 supports functions inside the batch file. However, you can do `CALL othercmd.bat` on an external batch file.

Comment: I ran it in win7,64x. I also have modified a WinPE that executes the batch file with no problem but it takes 3 to 4 mins. DOS is much faster.

Comment: the call command returns a syntax error when its run in DOS6.22

Comment: DOS 6.22 does not support for /f either.

Comment: So pretty much I have no choice than to stick with my modified WinPE?? thanks for your help guys much appreciated.

Comment: @user3165643 the syntax error is because DOS 6.22 doesn't support `CALL:function` within a batch file. It should support `CALL file.bat` for an external batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below for comments:

```
echo. This script is counting the # of POSTs.
echo. The POST # value is saved in TEST.txt.
echo.

call:myPOSTTest
```

MSDOS doesn't support the call :label syntax

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (A:\TEST.txt)  do echo POST# %%x
```

MSDOS doesn't support the extended `for` commands

```
echo. &pause&goto:eof
```

MSDOS doesn't support the `&` command separator or the `goto :eof` link

```
::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------

:myPOSTTest    - here starts my function identified by its label 

set var=0

if EXIST A:\TEST.txt (
     for /f %%x in (A:\TEST.txt) do (set /a var=%%x+1)
)
```

MSDOS doesn't support the compound expressions in parentheses or the `set /a` enhancement

```
echo %var% >> A:\TEST.txt

goto END

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but ...

The `call :function` syntax can be substituted by an additional file for each function or by trampoline code on the batch file entry.

```
@echo off
for %%P in (/%1.) do if %%P==: goto %1

echo Program started

call %0 :func1
call %0 :func2 With :args 
goto :eof

:func1
echo This is func1 with args: %1, %2, %3
goto :eof

:func2
echo This is func2 with args: %1, %2, %3
goto :eof

:eof
```

For the arithmetic part in `set /a var=%%x+1` you can use an [inc.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38129315/463115) or [add.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223540/463115).

Even reading and processing lines from a text file is possible with old DOS.