# MSDOS 6.22 How to get batch directory?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have an old 386 computer (without windows) which has MSDOS 6.22. So I cannot use any solution that built on cmd.exe (part of windows)

I want to pass current bat script path and name to another program within this bat code.

I try to use `%CD%` but it looks like works only with cmd.exe
I try to use `%0` argument, but it hold only the name of bat instead of name with full path

```
@echo off
set myPath=%cd%
myprogram.exe %myPath%\%0
```

It doesn't work. The passed parameter is `\mybat.bat` when I started the bat program from it's directory with full name.
After the variables resolved, I want to something like this:

```
@echo off
myprogram C:\BATCH\MYBAT.BAT
```

Where the bat placed in `c:\batch` directory, and it name is `mybat.bat`

How can I do this?

Comment: You will probably find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210059/2152082) helpful.

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that the currently executing batch file is located in the current directory.

Comment: @RossRidge you are right, but my bat's location is not in path, and I not call from another directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210059/463115) of [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) is good, but requires a predefined helper file.

But you can also build a solution which doesn't need any predefined files.

```
@echo off

>temp1.bat echo @PROMPT SET _CD=$P
>temp2.bat command /c temp1.bat
call temp2.bat
del temp1.bat
del temp2.bat

echo currentDir=%_CD%
```

This can be used to get the current directory `$P`, time `$T` or date `$D`, as these values are supported by the **PROMPT** command.

Comment: please remove space before ">" becouse it stored in the variable... my edit was declined

Answer (score 2):

- write current working folder to a file
- combine with another prepared file
- call the resulting batch file to get a variable
- use as usual

The trick is to create a secondary batch file with just one command: `set VARIABLE=somestring`. We achieve that by concatenating a prepared file with `set VARIABLE=` (important: **without** a line feed) and another file with the desired value.

```
@echo off
cd>temp.txt
copy init.txt+temp.txt setvar.bat
call setvar.bat
myprogram.exe "%VARIABLE%\mybat.bat"
```

To create `init.txt` (you need to do that only one time (reusable file)):
Type `COPY CON INIT.TXT` on the command prompt.
Enter `@SET VARIABLE=^Z` (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to generate `^Z`)
Sadly I don't know a way to create a line without a line feed with code in DOS)

[Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59544933/2152082) answered with an interesting solution to get the working folder, but this one is more generic; it works with the output of any command (as long as it's one line only).
Just for example, replace `cd>temp.txt` with `dir | find "bytes free" > temp.txt` in above code.

(answer derived from an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210059/2152082) of mine)