# Current directory in DOSBox [Optional: Using TURBO C]

Tags: batch-file, dos, cd, dosbox, turbo-c

I want to run a command in a specific directory and then return back. (There is a reason for it [validity of parameters...]).

I tried doing it in batch file for DOSBox...

```
@echo off
cd>cd.cd
cd %mypath%
dosomething 1 2 3
::I am not sure....
cd (type cd.cd)
```

`%CD%`, `%dI`, `FOR` loop nothing works in DOSBox...

I wrote a C program but couldn't find a function that returns the current directory for TURBO C 16-bit...

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`%CD%` is a variable in Windows cmd](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386) so you can't use it in MS-DOS. You can work around that by storing the current directory output from the `cd` command without any parameters into a variable by redirecting command output to file then [read the file from disk](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66292/)

- Prepare a file containing only `@set cd=` without any newlines. It can be created in DOS by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> while running `COPY CON`. Let's name it init.txt
- Then everytime you want to get the current directory run

  ```
  cd >cd.txt
  copy init.txt+cd.txt setcd.bat
  setcd
  ```
- The last command will save the current directory into the `%CD%` variable

[image: Get current dir]

Comment: Is there any way to append a string on the same line DOS?

Comment: Actually my DOSBox hangs on `copy con <file-name>` for some reason.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow it's not hanging. It's waiting for you to enter the content because [`CON` is the keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#DOS,_TOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows). See [copy con](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/copycon.htm). That's the reason why you can't [create a folder named “CON” in Windows (easily)](https://superuser.com/q/129141/241386)

Comment: Oh..That was pretty unexpected . Is there any way by which we can write on the same line instead with two different command?

Comment: something like `@echo set cd=(somespecialcharacter)>mp` and then `@cd>>mp`

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow you just prepare init.txt once and use it forever. No need to care about that file. `echo` writes a new line so you can't use echo to do that

Comment: Is there any way by which I can create a script that runs after every cd or drive change?

Comment: probably make a batch file that calls CD and does everything you want, and avoid using the original CD completely. But it's outside the scope of this question. You should ask a different one

Comment: @phuclv: That sounds somehow [familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210059/2152082)

Answer (score 1):

To get the current directory programmatically from Turbo C you need to read the [current directory structure (CDS)](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/348-cds__current_directory_structure.html). The current directory is the first 67-byte field containing a null-terminated string

To get the address of the first CDS you use the 52h function of DOS int 21h (set AH=52h). Following CDS can be obtained by adding an offset to the first address. For more information read

- [Format of current directory structure (CDS) (array, LASTDRIVE entries)](http://faydoc.tripod.com/structures/16/1643.htm)
- [PC Mag Aug 1991](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=JkmqysqcLI0C&pg=PT480&lpg=PT480&dq=current%20directory%20struct%20cds%20address%20dos&source=bl&ots=JJHkw3jH8f&sig=ACfU3U2GPU9mx3lqUqSCDFRDp_zeCDmZcw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDjeGj0M7nAhWLyDgGHSx4AngQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=snippet&q=%22current%20directory%20structures%22&f=false)
- [PC Mag 9 Nov 1993](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=NGX-Fo9YqzcC&pg=PA366&lpg=PA366&dq=current%20directory%20struct%20cds%20address%20dos&source=bl&ots=rw4COQNAN9&sig=ACfU3U3ZzKx_GBardIOLMXXRqHg-R7cZGA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDjeGj0M7nAhWLyDgGHSx4AngQ6AEwCXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22current%20directory%20structure%22&f=false)
- [PC Mag 25 Jun 1991](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=DXn-87kyJksC&pg=PT369&lpg=PT369&dq=call%20dos%20function%20assembly%2052h&source=bl&ots=ZMubXm_A3t&sig=ACfU3U2B4fKd0uMH55UgFDBHoHA2hkl0oA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG3aqG1M7nAhU44zgGHbEsDGIQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=52h&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

> 1. **The command method** (@phuclv's first answer) (Drawback: A permanent file needs to be maintained)
> 2. **The assembly method** (@phuclv's first answer) (Drawback: I can't really find any way to perform system calls in assembly, it would be great if someone could provide a example and ask some privileged user to edit this answer to remove this info)
> 3. **The TURBOC method** (Since I was anyways writing C90 code, I just used the way I anyways was going to.)

Here's the sample C90 Code which can be used to get and perform some operation on in TURBOC3:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<string.h>

void main()
{

  char path[128];
  system("cd>__p_");
  fscanf(fopen("__p_","r"),"%[^\n]",path);
  remove("__p_");

  //path variable/array/pointer contains your current path.

  //printf(path);

  //strcat(command,path); //char command[128]="cd ";
  //system(command); 

}
```

Comment: Can't you use Turbo-C's `getcwd` function to get the current working directory? http://www.x-hacker.org/ng/borcpp/ng2e153.html

Comment: You can just use [`intdos()`](https://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/Reference/tc/ng30db2.html) to run the interrupt, no need to use inline assembly. But even if you want to use inline assembly just `mov ah, 52h; int 21h` after saving necessary registers. But otherwise use [`getcurdir`](https://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/Reference/tc/ng2b451.html) or `getcwd`