# Why won't this increment work in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Why will this not increment? I am using this in a batch file. It does everything correctly, except it doesn't increment. What am I doing wrong?

```
@SET variable=1
@echo How many increments should be created?
@set /p increments=
@echo off

@FOR /l %%x in (1, 1, %increments%) do @(
@SET /A variable=variable+1
@echo %variable%
)

@ECHO Program Complete!
@pause
```

Edit: This is not a duplicate, this is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "variable=1"
set /p "increments=How many increments should be created? "
echo off

FOR /l %%x in (1, 1, %increments%) do (
SET /A "variable=!variable!+1"
echo !variable!
)

ECHO Program Complete!
pause
```

Within a loop (or if) you should use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!` instead of `%`

I also changed your `set /p`, because you can give a string to echo to `set /p` itself instead of using `echo` above it, and put double quotes around your sets so it will not error for values like spaces. Note that when you try to enter a string instead of a number it will simply not loop, instead of crashing

**EDIT:**

an easier version with only the loop-variables themselves (%%x) and without delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
SET "variable=1"
set /p "increments=How many increments should be created? "
set /a "forincrements=increments+1"
FOR /l %%x in (%variable%, 1, %forincrements%) do (
  echo %%x
)
ECHO Program Complete!
pause
```

Comment: Edited a bit more. I also recommend you take a look at [this](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Dennis van Gils' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34601119/5047996) already shows you what is missing -- delayed variable expansion.

You are using the syntax `set /A variable=variable+1` (which operates quite the same as delayed expansion like `set /A variable=!variable!+1`).
However, you can use an alternative syntax to avoid need of delayed expansion: `set /A variable+=1`:

```
for /L %%x in (1, 1, %increments%) do (
    set /A "variable+=1"
)
echo %variable%
```

Of course the `echo` does no longer work within the loop if delayed expansion is disabled, so I moved it outside of the loop to show just the final result, using standard (immediate) expansion.

Comment: My guess was that he need the results inside the loop, and that's why he tried to echo them there too. Your answer works, except for when he has to use those results

Comment: Yes, I guess so too, but I just wanted to show this possibility... anyway, he could use `%%x` within the loop...

Comment: Yes, that's why I made the edit. I guess it's best to show all the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of Dennis' solution above. Notice the set /a command. Of course, in this case you don't really need the var "variable", but I suppose it's an assignment where you are required to use it. In a more general setting you could need it.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set variable=1
set /p increments=How many increments should be created? 

for /l %%x in (1, 1, %increments%) do (
    echo !variable!
    set /a variable += 1
)

echo Program Complete!
```

Comment: You *really* should post some *explanation*.

Answer (score 0):

Well I used both for and if in this solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A i = 1
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (temp.txt) do (

    IF !i!==2 echo %%f
    SET /a i+=1
)
```