# Increment a variable on each cycle in a batch file?

Tags: loops, batch-file, variables

I have a batch script which loops and I want to count how many cycles it has done.

This is how the script looks:

```
@echo off
title MyTitle
set cycles=0
:startpoint
echo %cycles%
(my command)
goto startpoint
```

I would like to be able to see the variable "cycles" increment by `1` each time it goes back to `:startpoint`, how do i do that?

Comment: What is stopping you from using the `SET` command to add one to the variable?  Open up a command prompt and type: `set /?` This will show you the syntax for doing arithmetic expressions using the `SET` command.

Comment: The OP might not be aware of the `set /a` switch, in which case doing `set cycles=%cycles%+1` would output `0+1` and then `0+1+1` instead of `1` and then `2`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To perform arithmetic operations in batch you need to use the `/a` switch with the `set` command:

```
@echo off
title MyTitle
set cycles=0

:startpoint
set /a cycles=cycles+1
echo %cycles%
...
(my command)
...
goto startpoint
```

Type `set /?` in cmd for more information.

Comment: thank you this code works perfectly, I could not find anything on the web

Comment: worth mentioning: also possible (and you will see it often): `set /a count +=1`

Comment: if you find in for loop the variable not increment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600979/why-wont-this-increment-work-in-batch

Answer (score 1):

Using this code

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (config.properties) do (
  set /a count += 1
  echo !count!
)
endlocal
```

works for me, the reason because I was using %count% instead of !count! so I keep getting 1 instead of the expected output. So if using `%%` doesn't work for you, you can as well use `!!` to either display your output or do your calculations or comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

well this worked for me.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A i = 1
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (temp.txt) do (

    IF !i!==2 echo %%f
    SET /a i+=1
)
```