# Batch counter not increasing

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Code is self explanatory. I have tried the commands in the commented lines with equal results. Last lines are test of incremental assignment and evidence enabledelayedexpansion works. The fault must lie within the for loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count_k=5

for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
rem set a/ count_k+=1
rem set a/ "count_k+=1"
set a/ count_k=count_k+1
echo This is count_k per   %count_k%
echo This is count_k exc  !count_k!
)

echo After loop this is count_k %count_k%

set _var=first
set _var=second & echo %_var% !_var!

set count = 0
(
set /a count+=1
echo %count% fails
echo !count! works
)
```

This is the output of the above batch file:

```
This is count_k per   5
This is count_k exc  5
This is count_k per   5
This is count_k exc  5
This is count_k per   5
This is count_k exc  5
This is count_k per   5
This is count_k exc  5
This is count_k per   5
This is count_k exc  5
After loop this is count_k 5
first second
 fails
1 works
```

Comment: Cmd.exe, despite appearances, has nothing to do with DOS. If you are writing new scripts, don't bother with batch. Use PowerShell.

Comment: hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697199/how-to-increment-variable-under-dos

Comment: Shouldn't it be `set /a` instead of `set a/`?

Comment: You are setting a variable named `a/ count_k`; re-check your syntax...

Comment: Ignore Bill_Stewart; his gimmick is coming into questions with the batch-file tag and telling the OP to use PowerShell.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with telling someone to use a vastly superior tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen the "a/" parameter to the "set" command before.  Are you sure it is not intended to be "/a", which could be hosing your results and your code?

I hate to hand out fish instead of teaching to fish, but is this similar to what you are trying to do?

```
@ECHO OFF
SET COUNT=0
ECHO Before the loop count is: %COUNT%

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,5) DO (
  @ECHO Loop %%A
  SET /A COUNT=%COUNT%+%%A
)

ECHO Outside the loop count is: %COUNT%
```

The output looks like this:

```
Before the loop count is: 0
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 3
Loop 4
Loop 5
Outside the loop count is: 5
```

By REMarking out the @ECHO OFF, it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\loginID>REM @ECHO OFF

C:\Users\loginID>SET COUNT=0

C:\Users\loginID>ECHO Before the loop count is: 0
Before the loop count is: 0

C:\Users\loginID>FOR /L %A IN (1 1 5) DO (

 SET /A COUNT=0+%A
)

C:\Users\loginID>(

 SET /A COUNT=0+1
)
Loop 1

C:\Users\loginID>(

 SET /A COUNT=0+2
)
Loop 2

C:\Users\loginID>(

 SET /A COUNT=0+3
)
Loop 3

C:\Users\loginID>(

 SET /A COUNT=0+4
)
Loop 4

C:\Users\loginID>(

 SET /A COUNT=0+5
)
Loop 5

C:\Users\loginID>ECHO Outside the loop count is: 5
Outside the loop count is: 5
```

Notice that inside the loop, the reference to %COUNT% is always 0 (from before entering the loop) no matter how many times we reset it inside the loop.  If I make a change inside the loop to

SET /A COUNT+=%%A

My final result echoing %COUNT% will result in 15.  Beyond this, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, a simple dyslexic error was causing all my troubles...

Answer (score 0):

This works with Windows 7 console window:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count_k=5
for /l %%a in (1 1 5) do (
set /a count_k=!count_k!+1
echo !count_k! 
)
```

Note that echo %count_k% will output 5, since %...% is similar to C preprocessor that does string substitutions before actually running the batch file.

Comment: just curious: why do you start every line with `@` despite of `@echo off`?

Comment: @Stephan - Just habit, as you mentioned it wasn't needed. I often cut and paste the batch files, some of which don't have the echo off. It's fixed now.