# Increase a global environmental variable in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, environment-variables

I used **setx** to set a global counter variable in my list of batch files, which are running in **parallel**.
I set first counter like this:

```
setx counter 1
```

But how to increase this variable in another batch file? I tried following but didn't work and it set "%counter%+1" in counter:

```
setx counter %counter%+1
```

Comment: `set /a counter+=1 && setx counter %counter%`

Comment: @Daemon-5: [I wouldn't expect this to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)

Comment: @Stephan: I suppose it wouldn't work because environment variables aren't stored in registry but in the CMD-session. The better way is to keep value in registry directly: `reg add ...`

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: If you want to change environment variable **in series** (step by step) use common database: Registry. But if your batch files are executing in the same time (dynamically) try to use values accessible for other process: *window title names*. For example. First batch-file: `title batchfile1=101`. Second batch-file: `title batchfile2=102`. Where 101,102 are counter's values. To find process with appropriate window's title use command: `tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq batchfile*" /fo list /v`

Comment: Actually I need to set an absolute counter in multiple batch files which are running in parallel

Comment: @Daemon-5 `set` stores it in the current `cmd` environment, `setx` stores it in the registry.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: not going to work: Your `cmd` instance receives a copy  of the "global" variables by creation. They don't update. You'll have to read the registry each time you want the updated value. Tip: don't mess with the registry, use a file instead (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841506/batch-file-read-in-var-and-write-back/18849507#18849507) for inspiration)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading first my long answer on the question: [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) The chapter **B)** describes the storage location of persistent stored environment variables. The chapter **F)** describes with an example that no process can modify environment variables of another already running process.

The solution for managing a variable `Counter` as persistent stored **user** environment variable would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Counter=0"
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,3" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY HKCU\Environment /v Counter 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Counter" set "Counter=%%J"
set /A Counter+=1
%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe Counter %Counter% >nul
endlocal
```

There is first defined in the **local** environment an environment variable `Counter` with value `0`.

Next a registry query is executed to get the current value of the persistent stored **user** environment variable `Counter` and assign this value to **local** environment variable `Counter` if existing at all in the registry hive of the current user.

The value of the **local** environment variable `Counter` is incremented by one.

The new value is written back to the registry for updating the value of the persistent stored **user** environment variable **Counter** using **SETX** which sends the message [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) to all top-level application windows.

There could be used instead of the **SETX** command line also:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKCU\Environment /f /v Counter /d %Counter% >nul
```

That command line updates also the value of persistent stored **user** environment variable `Counter` but without sending the Windows message `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` and working also on Windows XP which does not have `%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe`.

A deletion of the persistent **user** environment variable `Counter` requires the execution of the command line:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe DELETE HKCU\Environment /f /v Counter >nul
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`
- `reg delete /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `setx /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `reg` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` as additional arguments.

**Note:** If two running batch files execute the three command lines four to six more or less at the same time, the value of persistent stored **user** environment variable `Counter` is incremented just by one instead of by two because of both batch files read the same value at the same time from the registry, increment the value locally and both update the value in registry with same value. There would be more code necessary to handle such a parallel `Counter` value update use case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the answer, just some ideas.

1. You can use new cmd window's name for counter without `SETX` or `REG.EXE`.

Kill same processes:
`taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq counter*" /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"`

Then start new process: `start cmd /k title counter 100`
(for example counter value equals 100)

To search for window name with current counter value use command:
`for /f "delims=, tokens=9" %%i in ('tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq counter*" /fo csv /nh /v') do set "counter= %%~i"`

To get value:
`set "counter=%counter:*counter =%"`

2. If you plan to use `SETX` get counter value by Powershell: `powershell -nop -c [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('counter','user')`.

But it is cranky way because improved *PS* replaced *Batch Scripting*. So there is no reason to mix these tools.

P.S. And there is the way to execute batch with actual environment variables (described on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261156/)): `start /i /wait "" "%windir%\explorer.exe" batch-file.cmd`